# How to change button color?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing a GUI application using Embarcadero VCL c++ IDE for windows OS. As part of this project, I have to change color of button with respect to an external state.
I understood that windows32 API will not allow to change the color of button.
Could you please suggest me, how to change button color?

Comment: You might want to tag this with winapi or something so people know what API you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to change the background-colour of the button, or the text-colour of it?

Since windows has used visual themes for some time now, if you have commctrl loaded and include a manifest file, the button will be drawn using the default (current) theme.

Options I can see include (a) custom-drawing the background (b) changing the text-colour in the normal draw process (c) drawing the button without a theme (i.e drawing a 'flat' button).

You could simply draw a bitmap-button, changing the bitmap depending on the state of the button. You could also use a single bitmap, tinting it using the HSL or HSV colour-space, depending on the state.

As for the flat type of button, I think you can probably change it's background-colour in much the same way as you can change the colour of the text - by intervening during the standard draw process and changing the colour from 3D_FACE (or whatever it is, I forget) to whatever you'd like.

If you look at the calculator included with windows XP, you can see an example of changing the text colour.

CodeProject.com likely has a stack of articles that would help in this endeavour. :)

Comment: I wish to change the back-ground colour (NOT TEXT) of the button. I created small coloured bitmaps and tried to show it on bitmap button. But, this bitmap image not covering total button. I will look into your suggestions. once again thanks for your reply.